# try-with-resource close sequence : FileInputStream close executed three times

Tags: java, debugging, java-7, try-with-resources

I was trying a simple `try-with-resource` example using Java 8 on OS X.
I see some strange behavior. First, following is the code I am running:

```
 public void test() {

        try( FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/tmp/test");
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test1")
                ){

            System.out.println("Nothing here");
            System.out.println("Nothing here");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error "  + e);
        }
    }
```

The application runs fine and prints `Nothing here` twice as expected.
When I run this in debug mode (IntelliJ idea), execution pauses twice at `FileInputSteam::close()` and then pauses at `FileOutputStream::close()` and then again pauses at `FileInputStream::close()` - To check the source of this behavior, I looked at the `.class` file through jad-gui. It shows following code :

```
public void test()
  {
    try
    {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/tmp/test");Throwable localThrowable6 = null;
      try
      {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test1");Throwable localThrowable7 = null;
        try
        {
          System.out.println("Nothing here");
          System.out.println("Nothing here");
        }
        catch (Throwable localThrowable1)
        {
          localThrowable7 = localThrowable1;throw localThrowable1;
        }
        finally {}
      }
      catch (Throwable localThrowable4)
      {
        localThrowable6 = localThrowable4;throw localThrowable4;
      }
      finally
      {
        if (fin != null) {
          if (localThrowable6 != null) {
            try
            {
              fin.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable localThrowable5)
            {
              localThrowable6.addSuppressed(localThrowable5);
            }
          } else {
            fin.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Error " + e);
    }
  }
```

This is more confusing.

**Why the decompiled code does not show any call to** `FileOutputStream::close()` - is it an issue with jd-gui ?

**Why during debug the control goes twice to** `FileInputStream::close()` first? Is this some bug or is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I have no idea, but if I had to guess, I would think that FileOutputStream internally closes FileInputStreams during its own closing process. Has anyone looked at the source for that? All you have data on is the class, not the specific instance.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin How, and why, would `FileOutputStream` close a `FileInputStream` that it can't even see?

Comment: Your decompiler must be wrong. Here's how IntelliJ's own decompiler decompiles your code: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/6bbd5a1efc994438a3d6

Comment: @JBNizet - thanks for the link. Looks like issue with JD GUI. I will further debug and see if I can figure out why additional close calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment of @jb-nizet your decompiler did not show the correct things, which explains your question 1.

For question 2 have a look at the Stream.path variable in the debugger. On my System this are not the Streams openend by you but Java 8 internal files like "/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/tzdb.dat", "/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/meta-index" and the class itself. But I only have one call for the InputStream "/tmp/test" and one for the Output Stream "/tmp/test1".

Comment: Thanks! I looked at things more closely based on your response. While debug, two file input stream gets closed, which is not related to the code. It is java internal as you mentioned `tzdb.dat` and `MyTest.class` files. That confused me previously as I thought all were getting closed on behalf of my code. Given that, the closing sequence is working as expected.